# Change gravity of image drawable in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-drawable, android-gravity

I've added image Drawable start in a TextView . Problem is i cant control the gravity of that Drawable in TextView

What i need to achieve 
[image: What i need to achieve]

What i have achieved so far

[image: What i have achieved so far]

This is my TextView

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_8_digit_check"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dimen_4"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_validate"
            android:text="@string/at_least_8_characters_txt"
            android:textColor="@color/white_trans"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
```

Any suggestion on how can i set gravity of that Drawable to top/start? Thanks

Comment: An easy to use solution could be here https://github.com/imbeerus/compound-text-view. But it seems to have deprecated dependencies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Try using  `android:gravity="top"`

   **if it didnt work then go with negative margin like this**
2. `android:drawablePadding="-20sp"`
3. Another alternative way is to take an `ImageView` beside
    `TextView` inside `LinearLayout` so you can apply gravity

Comment: gravity top not working in my case. and about padding i already have to assign some padding for other purpose.

Comment: then go for the third idea

Comment: yes end up doing the third solution. i know that solution but i thought someone might have better solution for this. thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use checkbox instead of textview Drawable, and add custom drawable where you can use this image

Comment: You can change CheckBox drawable `android:button="@drawable/your_drawable"
 android:gravity="top"
 android:paddingLeft="6dp"`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put image to imageview. Put the imageview and the textview in a Linearlayout and set gravity to `top`. Reduce the size of text and image too.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="top">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_4"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_validate"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_8_digit_check"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/at_least_8_characters_txt"
        android:textColor="@color/white_trans"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i know this solution would work. but the problem is nesting layouts. and view optimization if it was for adding another view in the layout why android built compound drawable to be set in the same TextView ?

Comment: Usually when text is short compound drawable is good idea, but when you want something custom it can't help. You can put android:maxLines="1" and reduce text size, but it can cause a problem on small screens.

Comment: Also you can create additional TextView for "Character" under main TextView

Answer (score 0):

Use checkbox instead of textview and disable click and focus of that view

```
<CheckBox
        android:gravity="top"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_right_managed"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        text="I look like a check box but beware I'm not"/>
```